# When trees are the answer: what is the question?

Tags: optimization, big-list, trees

For which optimization problems are (abstract) trees the best solution?

E.g. [binary search trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) are somehow optimal data structures for quick search.

But why for example do botanic trees grow as they grow?

More examples are welcome! (not necessarily *optimization* problems)

Comment: Plants are not always trees in the topological sense. They might grow at first as trees, because it might be inconvinient to join branches (imagine merging with no version control), however, merging does happen, see [natural grafting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting#Natural_grafting) and [inosculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inosculation). Also, plants like [Ivy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy) might be so convoluted that I doubt "tree" is a good term to name their structure (even if they are in theory).

Answer (score 1):

Binary search trees are **not** the optimal data structures for efficient searching in some models of computation. Generally it is when you want dynamic data structures supporting insert and delete that balanced binary trees are usually able to provide good worst-case guarantees. As for botanic trees, a largely recursive structure can be described using very little information, and it may be a partial reason why many structures in nature are recursive and often tree-like.

Comment: Having a largely recursive structure is not an evolutionary advantage per se. Why is it advantageous to be tree-shaped?

Comment: @HansStricker: I didn't say it is an evolutionary advantage! Why would you assume that it must be? Nor did I say it isn't. All I said was that a recursive structure has a relatively short description compared to its size and hence may partially explain why some large structures in nature are recursive. I also said "often tree-like", not always. For example fractals are another kind of recursive structure that occurs naturally in many places. Tree-like structures tend to be found together with some kind of growth since recursively growing a tree-like structure is "easy".

Comment: I did not want to insinuate anything about what you said, sorry! But I was assuming that my question "why do trees grow as they grow?" was understood as "what's the evolutionary advantage of the way trees grow?". You are right that there doesn't have to be such an advantage. But maybe there is one, and I personally believe *that* there is one. But I cannot tell which one.

Comment: @HansStricker: Don't worry; I understand that it is common to first assume the evolutionary hypothesis and then find evidence in favour of it. It's obvious that there must be some reason that trees grow the way they do, but it doesn't necessarily have to be an evolutionary reason. For example, there is some reason your computer is the way it is, but its design is (largely) not due to random errors. In any case the fact that simple rules can generate large and flexible structures (think of phototropism and geotropism) is an advantage to the plant, evolutionary or not.

Comment: Until further notice: This is an interesting article about the simulated growth of realistic trees: https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall02/cps124/resources/p119-weber.pdf

Comment: And another interesting article on *Structural simulation of
tree growth*: http://graphics.cs.illinois.edu/sites/graphics.dev.engr.illinois.edu/files/structsim.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A **Fenwick tree** or **Binary indexed tree** is a structure for storing *prefix sums* of an array of numbers so that modifying a number and calculating a specific prefix sum can both be done in $O(\log n)$ time where $n$ is the number of elements, while still using only $n$ memory locations.

See http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Updating_partial_sums_with_Fenwick_tree for a nice technical description.